# Cryptanalysis of MD4 (Wang et al) -- how did the authors come up with the collision differential?

Tags: collision-resistance, differential-analysis, md4

Edit: 
ok, after I re-read the paper a couple of times it is clear that Table 6 is  easily derived from Table 5, which describes the collision differential. So the real question is: how did the authors come up with the collision differential?

Original question:

The paper [Cryptanalysis of the Hash Functions
MD4 and RIPEMD](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/11426639_1.pdf) describes a set of sufficient conditions for collisions of MD4 (Table 6 in the paper). The authors explain how to verify these conditions, but there is no info about how they got them in the first place. I'm curious, what could be a possible procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the following tweet:

> [...] all the papers I've read say that she found the right difference patterns by "intuition"

(https://twitter.com/ghostly_gray/status/906009834755055617)

I'll happily accept another, more specific answer!